# R counting a field in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, aggregate

I have a data table which could be reduced to this:

```
set.seed(1); 
dt<-data.table(form=c(1,1,1,2,3,3,3,4,4,5),
    mx=c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","e","g","b"),
    vr=runif(10,100,200),
    usr=c("l","l","l","m","o","o","o","l","l","m"),
    type=c("A","A","A","C","C","C","C","C","C","A"))
```

I can generate a table with:

```
dt[,
    list(n.form=length(unique(form)),n.mx=length(unique(mx)),tot.vr=sum(vr)),
    by=usr]
```

What I haven't been able to to is to count the number of formulas of type A (each row is an observation, the `form` is the formula number). I've tried:

```
dt[,
    list(n.form=length(unique(form)),n.mx=length(unique(mx)),tot.vr=sum(vr),n.A=sum(type=="A"),
    by=usr]
```

and also:

```
dt[,
    list(n.form=length(unique(form)),n.mx=length(unique(mx)),tot.vr=sum(vr),n.A=length(unique(type=="A"))),
    by=usr]
```

but none of those takes into account the fact that the number of "A"  found needs to be related to the unique formula (`form`) number.

What I'd like to have as a result is:

```
   usr n.form n.mx   tot.vr n.A
1:   l      2    5 750.0398   1
2:   m      2    2 296.9994   1
3:   o      1    3 504.4747   0
```

but I can't find a way to achieve it. Any light shed is much appreciated.
Thanks,

======= **EDIT TO ADD** ========

I want to know how many of the formulas (unique numbers in `dt$form`) are of type "A" (so I can calculate a proportion out of total formulas). The direct number (`sum`) is the total number of *observations* of type A, while the existence (`any`) gives me if there was at least one formula of type "A", **but not** the number of formulas of that type (which is what I want). Please notice that any given formula will *always* be either of type "A" or "C" (not mixed types in one formula)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the `devel` version of `data.table`, you can use `uniqueN` instead of `length(unique(..`,

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
dt[,list(n.form=uniqueN(form), n.mx=uniqueN(mx),tot.vr=sum(vr),
            n.A=uniqueN(form[type=='A'])) , by = usr]
#    usr n.form n.mx   tot.vr n.A
#1:   l      2    5 750.0398   1
#2:   m      2    2 296.9994   1
#3:   o      1    3 504.4747   0
```

Comment: Your code runs well on the provided data, but if I introduce this change: `dt$usr<-c(dt$usr[1:9],"l")` then it fails to add an additional formula (`form==5`) to the `n.A`, which should show now a 2.

Comment: @PavoDive I may have misunderstood your question.  Sorry.

Comment: @PavoDive I updated the post.  Can you check the results now.  Based on the your changed code the `n.A` would be `2 0 0`